# NodeJS - how to stop running a script execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, node-inspector

I'm developping a NodeJS application, and sometimes I get my CPU usage at 100%, with no memory variation (I check this with pm2 monit) and with my Event Loop blocked by this operation.

So I remember that browsers do something interesting when a script seems to have a problem, and they show a popup like: "Do you want to continue running script on this page or stop it".

Is there a way to have the same behavior with NodeJS? I want to detect an operation which takes too many time, and trigger something that I can catch by pm2 to force restart, or (better) by node-inspector where it could break on the bad script and so I could understand what is the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nope, but you should probably profile it next time it happens and produce a flame graph to figure out the hot path.

Comment: Yes, for debug it I can profile it, but with profiling, I cannot detect and restart the process when it happens, can I?
But ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

your can stop the node server or check the task list for windows and stop the services whatever services you want.

Comment: It happens on my production server, so I cannot use task manager of Windows (I use Linux server).
I know I can stop the server, but I want something more efficient to detect and trace some usefull information to debug it.